# When is it necessary to define __getattr__() and __setattr()__ methods for a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The official Python Programming FAQ advises the programmer to define the methods [`object.__getattr__(self, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [`object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) under certain circumstances when implementing the OOP concept of *delegation*. However, I can't find good general advice on **when defining these two methods is necessary, customary, or useful**.

---

The Python Programming FAQ's [example](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-delegation) is the following code

```
class UpperOut:

    def __init__(self, outfile):
        self._outfile = outfile

    def write(self, s):
        self._outfile.write(s.upper())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._outfile, name)
```

"to implement[] a class that behaves like a file but converts all written data to uppercase". The accompanying text also contains a vague note telling the programmer to define `__setattr__` in a careful way whenever attributes need to be set/modified (as opposed to just being read).

One question about this code is why their example doesn't use inheritance, which would presumably take care of what `__getattr__` does. However, as one commenter kindly pointed out, `file` doesn't exist as a distinct type in Python 3, which may point us to an answer: Maybe they wanted to illustrate pure delegation (that is: **delegation without inheritance**) as one use case of overwriting `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. (If one uses plain inheritance, attributes are inherited by default and hence don't need to be accessed explicitly via calls to `__getattr__` or `__setattr__`.)

For reference, a [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Delegation_(object-oriented_programming)&oldid=1117145858) of "delegation" from Wikipedia is the following:

> In object-oriented programming, **delegation** refers to evaluating a member [...] of one object [...] in the context of another [...] object [...]. Delegation can be done explicitly [...]; or implicitly, by the member lookup rules of the language [...]. Implicit delegation is the fundamental method for behavior reuse in prototype-based programming, corresponding to inheritance in class-based programming.

Even though the two concepts are often discussed together, delegation is not the same as [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)&oldid=1140506810):

> The term "inheritance" is loosely used for both class-based and prototype-based programming, but in narrow use the term is reserved for class-based programming (one class *inherits from* another), with the corresponding technique in prototype-based programming being instead called *delegation* (one object *delegates to* another).

Note that delegation is [uncommon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/381148/81063) in Python.

---

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123707/why-use-setattr-and-getattr-built-ins) on this site is about use cases of vanilla `getattr(object, name)` and `setattr(object, name, value)` and is not directly related.

Comment: When you want custom behavior when an attribute is set or fetched, or dynamically patch in more attributes. It's never necessary but it could make the object more convenient and easier to use correctly.

Comment: In the example that you link to, using `__getattr__` means that the `UpperOut` class doesn't have to implement all the methods of `file`; the only one it implements is `write`, because - for that method - it wants to have different behaviour. All other methods (and attributes) are derived from the underlying `file` object.

Comment: @Nick Thanks. I was wondering why their example doesn't use inheritance; wouldn't that take care of what `__getattr__` does here? Maybe they wanted to illustrate "delegation without inheritance", but then that would be one use case of overwriting `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`.

Comment: In this particular case, yes, I think you are right, since otherwise `UpperOut` is intended to be just like `file`. There's more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832536/when-to-use-delegation-instead-of-inheritance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: Awesome. Perhaps then "delegation without inheritance" is a possible class of answers to my question.

Comment: @Nick One nit: `file` doesn't exist as a distinct type in Python 3. `open` instead returns instances of various stream classes from the `io` module, depending on the arguments to `open`. (That's actually significant, as there is no longer *one* class to override in this case; calls are delegated to an *object*, no matter what type that object might have.)

Comment: @chepner Well, I did say "file object" in my first comment but then I guess I confused the issue with the second comment (I should have said "the file object" again or something similar). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: related question (there doesn't seem to be much on this topic): https://stackoverflow.com/q/63338641/2057969

Comment: Check out this answer I wrote a while back. The question was asking how to "choose whether an instance inherits from one class or another". That doesn't really fit with the inheritance paradigm, so I suggested using *delegation* instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746709/can-i-choose-the-parent-class-of-a-class-from-a-fixed-set-of-parent-classes-cond/56747123#56747123

Comment: Here is another answer with an example of delegation, this time *without* `__getattr__`, but instead, using the descriptor protocol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742625/dynamically-adding-builtin-methods-to-point-to-a-propertys-built-ins/59743116#59743116 And in the same question, here is another answer with yet another approach to delegation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59742860/5014455

Comment: As you have noted, inheritance is really a form of delegation. In class-based OOP languages, it is the first form that comes to mind. But if you look at other OOP flavors like *prototype-based OOP*, delegation is at the center of everything. One way to think about prototype-based OOP is that objects don't inherit from *types* they inherit from *other objects* (i.e. prototype). Javascript is one such language, although, pretty much everyone ignores the fundamental prototypal nature of the language and a class-based system has been grafted on to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just coincidentally I ran into an instance of this in the Python standard `ctypes` module not long ago, and it led me to ask a question: [Safe use of ctypes.create_string_buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75279666/5987)

Many of the functions in that module create objects that act as wrappers for simple C types, like `create_string_buffer` creates a wrapper for a simple char array.  Since the char array isn't a Python type, you can't work with it directly.  When for example you try to get the value of the `.raw` attribute, it returns a `bytes` object which is a *copy* of the internal array; this has to be done via a `__getattr__` call.  Similarly when you try to write to the `.raw` attribute you can't write to it directly, it must pass through a `__setattr__` call.